# What are the min and max parameters?

Tags: discussion, support

Several of the api methods (e.g. [questions](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=questions)) have min and max parameters with the following description:

> min (optional)
>
> - Minimum of the range to include in the current .
> - number
>
> max (optional)
>
> - Maximum of the range to include in the current .
> - number

This seems incomplete.  Can anyone explain what these parameters are for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah...  These are kind of complicated, but very flexible.  They're also getting better docs soon-ish.

Basically, `min` & `max` are the range of the sorted results to return.

So, if you order a list of questions (pick your API method of choice) by `votes`, you can set `min` to 5 and `max` to 10 to only return questions that have a score of at least 5 and no more than 10.

If you were to sort by `creation`, you could instead only return questions created between (inclusive) the 1st and 15th of June 2009 by setting `min` to 1243832400 and `max` to 1245042000.

Comparing pure strings (as in `name`) gives you *a* lexographic range though the exact one is something of an implementation detail.

Not specifying `min` or `max` causes that end of the range to by unbound.  So you could use get all questions with *at least* a score of 10 by setting `min` to 10, `sort` to `votes`, and omitting `max` on the appropriate methods.

Answer (score 2):

It may be useful to review the test cases in the [sample app](https://stackapps.com/questions/3/the-worlds-worst-stackoverflow-clone).

```
public void VotesMinMax()
{
    // min=2, max=4
    var coms = ApiProxy.GetUserCommentsByVotesWithRange(1, 1, 50, 2, 4);
    Assert.IsTrue(coms.Count() > 0, "Count");

    int lastVotes = Int32.MaxValue;

    foreach (var com in coms)
    {
        if (com.VoteCount > lastVotes)
            Assert.Fail("comments not ordered by Score");

        lastVotes = com.VoteCount;

        Assert.IsTrue(com.VoteCount <= 4 && com.VoteCount >= 2);
    }
}
```